# Page address is correct, but content is not

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have some route table in global.asax as follow:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("en_term", "en-us/Terms", "~/en_us/Term.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("en_about", "en-us/About", "~/en_us/AboutApp.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("en_comm", "en-us/Community/Feedback", "~/en_us/Community/Feedback.aspx");
```

and also have a link:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="footerContactLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%$RouteUrl:routename=en_comm%>" Text="Feedback"/>
```

when i click on this link, page navigate to `http://localhost:1384/en-us/Community/Feedback`
[image] 
but contents of the page belong to another page (Term.aspx)
I don't know whats happening and can't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a dumb dumb obvious one: is it possible that Feedback.aspx contains the same content as Term.aspx?

Comment: Feedback.aspx is empty.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @AndreCalil you need 50 rep for that

Comment: @meda I see, but he won't get it by giving unconstructive answers. Although he cannot *comment everywhere* yet, he must learn the difference between a "guess" answer and a "let's test" comment.